# Get the sum of polymorphic relationship models multiplied by pivot

Tags: laravel, eloquent

When using polymorphic relationships, how can I get the sum of a field of a morphed model, multiplied by a pivot value?

So, I have these tables:

```
- order (hasMany OrderItems)
    - ...
```

```
- order_item (morphTo)
    - orderable_id
    - orderable_type
    - quantity
```

```
product_type_a
    - price
    - ...
```

```
product_type_b
    - price
    - ...
```

```
product_type_c
    - price
    - ...
```

These are the models:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class);
    }
}

class OrderItem extends Model
{
    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }

    public function orderable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class ProductType extends Model
{
    public function orderItem()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(OrderItem::class, 'orderable');
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to retrieve is the sum of the `order_item.quantity` × `order_item.orderable.price`.

I tried, just to see the result, these queries (`$this` refers to the `Order` model in this context):

```
$this->items()->with('orderable')->sum('quantity');
```

Which returns the expected sum of the quantity of `order_items`.

```
$this->items()->with('orderable')->sum('price');
$this->items()->with('orderable')->sum('orderable.price');
$this->items()->with('orderable')->sum(DB::raw('price'));
$this->items()->with('orderable')->sum(DB::raw('orderable.price'));
```

Where all result in (similar errors, but basically unknown columns):

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'price' in 'field list' (SQL: select sum(price) as aggregate from `order_items` where `order_items`.`order_id` = ? and `order_items`.`order_id` is not null and `order_items`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

So, I can't access even the sum of prices of the morphed models. How can achieve the sum of `order_item.quantity` × `order_item.orderable.price`. So, for example:

```
product_type_a
    - id: 1
    - price: 1.00

product_type_b
    - id: 2
    - price: 2.00

order_item
    - quantity: 5
    - orderable_id: 1
    - orderable_type product_type_a

order_item
    - quantity: 10
    - orderable_id: 2
    - orderable_type product_type_b
```

The sum should be `(5 * 1.00)` + `(10 * 2.00)` = `25`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use an accessor to do the magic.

```php
class OrderItem extends Model
{
    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }

    public function orderable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function getCalculatedPriceAttribute(): int
    {
        return $this->quantity * $this->orderable->price;
    }
}
```

```php
$order = Order::with('items.orderable')->find($id);

$total = $order->items->sum('calculated_price');
```

If I'm not mistaken, you can go one step further and make the sum part an accessor as well.

```php
class Order extends Model
{
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class);
    }

    public function getCalculatedTotalAttribute(): int
    {
        return $this->items->sum('calculated_price');
    }
}
```

```php
$order = Order::with('items.orderable')->find($id);

$total = $order->calculated_total;
```